# What is the windows API to change Screen refresh rate?

Tags: winapi

Can some one specify the windows API, one need to use in order to be able to change programmatically the screen refresh rate?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found this via a google search. Hope it helps some.

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/winsdk/changerefresh.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms533260(VS.85).aspx

Answer (score 5):

you can use ChangeDisplaySettings as described before. But you should use EnumDisplaySettings to get a list of valid combinations of (color dept, width, height, mode and frequency).

Sample code (in Delphi but translation should be trivial)

**Get valid display modes**

```
i := 0;
while EnumDisplaySettings(nil, i, dm) do begin
  Memo1.Lines.Add(Format('Color Depth: %d', [dm.dmBitsPerPel]));
  Memo1.Lines.Add(Format('Resolution: %d, %d', [dm.dmPelsWidth, dm.dmPelsHeight]));
  Memo1.Lines.Add(Format('Display mode: %d', [dm.dmDisplayFlags]));
  Memo1.Lines.Add(Format('Frequency: %d', [dm.dmDisplayFrequency]));
  Inc(i);
end;
```

**Set display mode**

```
// In this case i is an index in the list of valid display modes.
if EnumDisplaySettings(nil, i, dm) then begin
  // Sanity check!
  if ChangeDisplaySettings(dm, CDS_TEST) = 0) then
    ChangeDisplaySettings(dm, 0);  // Use CDS_UPDATEREGISTRY if this is the new default mode.
end;
```

It is very important to chose a valid combination!

Comment: Delphi is one of my favorites:)